# How to stop redirection in IE?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone tell me how to redirect a page to another one in all browser except IE?

Actually now I have two website and I want the users of all other browsers redirect to my new site except IE users because it's still suitable for my old website.

Comment: It depends how you perform redirection. Any code to share? In general on the server you can check UserAgent to choose proper redirection (if any).

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<script>location.href = 'someUrl';</script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if !IE]>
code for not IE
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<!--[if !IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```